# How to Transfer Files Into Chromecast with Google TV?

Tags: chromecast

The new Chromecast with Google TV has a few gigs of free storage space but I can't figure out how to place files in there? There does not seem to be an obvious way to do that but it lets people install VLC which, of course does not find anything,

How do I load media files onto the Chromecast with Google TV? If there is anything to do so that they are visible to the installed VLC, that would be good to know too.

NOTE: Posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66174332/1260172) a few days ago on StackOverflow that has some Chromecast related questions but there were no answers. I will delete one of the two questions when there are answers on one.

Comment: Have you tried one of the file-explorer apps that also contain a server/web-ui (needs to be enabled separately in the app)?

Comment: Didn't know that existed but I understand the concept, so I'll try to find one.